# Anaconda activation fails

Tags: python, windows, cmd, anaconda

Essentially what the title says. Here is a snippet from cmd:

```
C:\Users\Marc>conda activate quantum

(quantum) C:\Users\Marc>py
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Ana
conda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'QuantumCircuit' from 'qiskit' (unknown location
)
>>>
```

This is despite the fact that I ran the command to activate an environment (`conda activate quantum`). The base environment does work, but I want to activate another environment.
For those curious, Anaconda navigator and pip freeze both show that qiskit is installed in this env.

Comment: "If you receive this warning, you need to activate your environment. To do so on Windows, run: c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base in Anaconda Prompt." Did you try this?

Comment: activating base works, but I want to activate another environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my mistake. I should've typed `python` to start the interpreter.